# Object design: Class property vs. list of objects

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, persistence

We have an object-oriented database. So, our persistence is truly object oriented.

The example is the object `person` and the attribute `VIP`. We have to store, if a person is a VIP or not. Usecase: Ordinary users of our application aren't allowed to see VIPs.

Now, my co-worker claims, not to store the attribute as property like `person.isVIP` but to hold all VIPs in an extra list, the `List<Person> vip-list`. He says "seldom used attributes should not be a property".

I don't feel that's right, but I don't have arguments for my case. Maybe you can help me out...

Comment: Why does he suggest this counterintuitive way of structuring your data? Is there a storage or performance reason? I think the right way should be the most logical and most expected structure by other developers who will have to maintain this.

Comment: Store your data in the manner that is most optimised for how you access it and expose your data in the manner that is most convenient for consumers. Don't design things arbitrarily in isolation.

Answer (score 2):

The answer as it often is, is "it depends".  You need to balance the advantages of each over the other based on your requirements.

## Property

- potentially less storage required.  In theory you only need a bit but in practical terms it will probably be more than that.
- simple to implement and understand

## List

- potentially less storage required.  If only a small fraction of people are in this set, you only need a little bit of data to store the VIP list.
- If you have lots of boolean properties to manage that are often rarely true, you can extend this approach to cover more such items.  If you keep having to add these, you can do it without changing `person` repeatedly.
- You won't have as much to worry about someone having the a person record open and dealing with record locking strategies when updating the VIP status.

I mention that space could be saved by either approach.  It depends on the fraction of your `person` records that are VIP.

> "seldom used attributes should not be a property"

This hints that your colleague might be arguing space usage.  I'm guessing (albeit with very little information) that any savings will be small to negligible.  You might want to do some analysis and determine the actual space savings.  Either you will find that they are significant or that they are not and then you can frame the discussion around facts.

Another thing to consider is that if your coworker has more experience than you within the context that you are building this system, they might know that locking is an issue or some other reason that maintaining it separately is going to be preferable.  You should ask for clarification on reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

I have more experience with document databases but many of the same principles apply here.  You don't want to store a `List<Person>` when you are already storing the data in another location.  At best, you would store a list of Person References.

There are trade-offs in either case.  The list can be generated at any time if you stored the information as an attribute.  But I have to ask the question whether he is as dogmatic about attributes that are not simple boolean values?  What would you do if the person's status was stored with a Rank enumeration?

```
public enum Rank {
    VIP,
    Preferred,
    Normal,
    Economy
}
```

In that case you would have to either have one list per enum value, or store it as a dictionary between the person reference and the rank assigned.  In either case, it's adding a level of complexity that makes less and less sense.

You can always easily query the object or document database to get all `Person`s with an attribute of `person.isVIP == true` or `person.rank = Rank.VIP`.  If that list is used often you can cache it for performance optimization.

That said, your argument is one of *predictability* and *complexity*.  As teammates you have to determine which approach is going to have the maximum predictability and the minimum complexity **overall**.  That means you have to consider how the information is used in downstream processing when you make the decision.

Comment: "You don't want to store a List<Person> when you are already storing the data in another location" - that's not necessarily true, particularly in NoSQL databases. If you can store multiple copies of a thing in different formats to satisfy different use cases then in many cases that is absolutely the right thing to do. In fact that is exactly what a view in most document stores does.

Comment: @AntP, I'm biased by working with more volatile data, but I see your point.  The crux of the matter is things should be stored in a way that lowers the system's complexity, and the behavior of the system is predictable.